# Chef API REST deprecated

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I'm trying to replace my deprecated Chef::REST API call with Chef::ServerAPI but I can't seem to make it work.

I'm initializing it like this:

```
def initialize(options={})

  @account_name = options[:account_name] or raise 'The chef account name has not been set'
  @client_name = options[:client_name] or raise 'The chef client name has not been set'
  @client_key = options[:client_key] or raise 'The chef client key has not been set'
  @cache = Config[:cache] or raise 'The chef_service client has not been configured'
  @cache_expiry = Config[:cache_expiry]
  @chef_status = ChefStatus.new(Config[:chef_status_url], Config[:chef_status_url_expiry])
end
```

and the actual call is in a method:

```
def rest
  @rest ||= Chef::REST.new(api_url, client_name, nil, raw_key: client_key)
end
```

I thought that I could just call:

```
def rest
  @rest ||= Chef::ServerAPI.new(api_url, client_name, nil, raw_key: client_key)
end
```

But that did not work at all. I would appreciate if someone can give me a pointer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say 'did not work', can you explain? do you have a stack trace to share?

Comment: There is not currently a supported library for making Chef HTTP calls.

Comment: ERROR:
Exception Class: ArgumentError
Unhandled exception: wrong number of arguments (given 4, expected 0..2) (from ArgumentError)
Backtrace:
 /Users/mauro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.5/gems/chef-12.22.5/lib/chef/server_api.rb:32:in `initialize'

Comment: coderanger, should I assume that I need to find some sort of wrapper/gem to make these chef calls now?